# center a check/tick within a custom check box

Tags: html, css, checkbox, styling

I am building a custom check box, the functionality is almost there but the styling has a way to go.

I have a few problems,

1. I need the check centered within the circle
2. I only need the check to be active on click of the checkbox itself not the text to.

Im afraid i cant seem to center the check without using padding left of position left.

**HTML**

```
<label for='product-45-45'>
  <input type='checkbox' style="float:left;" id='product-45-45' />
  <div class="accord-text">
    <strong>header:</strong> sub text
    <strong>more text!</strong>
  </div>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + .accord-text:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 200%;
  background-color: #d6e4ec;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "";
  color: green;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .accord-text:before {
  display: table;
  content: "\2713";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Problem 1: `text-align: center;` when checkbox ic checked, and remove `style="float:left;"` from checkbox
- Problem 2: Remove the text from `accord-text` div and put it outside.

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + .accord-text:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 200%;
  background-color: #d6e4ec;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 140%;
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "";
  color: green;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .accord-text:before {
  display: table;
  content: "\2713";
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <label for='product-45-45'>
  <input type='checkbox' style="float:left;" id='product-45-45' />
  <div class="accord-text">

  </div>
</label>

  <strong>header:</strong> sub text
  <strong>more text!</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: To get it all on one line do i just wrap it in a span ?

Comment: I'd prefer to use a div with flex-direction = row, but yes, using a span could be a good solution too.

Comment: checkbox is bigger when we checked , can you please avoid that

Comment: Yes, just get smaller font-size, we must keep a relation between both sizes. Take a look

Answer (score 2):

Check with this snippet also i have fixed the height issue when we checked ,

Add `display:block` and `max-height` to  this `input[type=checkbox]:checked + .accord-text:before`

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
label {
float:left;
}
input[type=checkbox] + .accord-text:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 200%;
  background-color: #d6e4ec;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "";
  color: green;
  text-align:center;
  max-height:30px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .accord-text:before {
  display: table;
  content: "\2713";
  max-height:30px;
  display:block;
}
span {
float:left;
padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<label for='product-45-45'>
  <input type='checkbox' style="float:left;" id='product-45-45' />
  <div class="accord-text"></div>
</label>
<span><strong>header:</strong> sub text
  <strong>more text!</strong>
</span>
```

Comment: check with now , there is no jump with check box when clicked

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the inline code that's styling the input to float left, you can't center it while that float is on. Then add margin: 0 auto to center it:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  float: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + .accord-text:before {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 200%;
  background-color: #d6e4ec;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "";
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: no, ive checked this on a fiddle and dose not work, thanks anyways