# How to display the check mark when choosing the checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a checkbox and I changed the checkbox style in a circle. Now I need when the user chooses the checkbox then I have to display the check mark.

If I remove `-webkit-appearance: none;` then I am getting it but my css not working.

How can I do this?

```css
.checkbox_round {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.checkbox_round:hover {
  border-color: #000;
}

.checkbox_round:checked {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="name1" value="1" class="checkbox_round"> check box1 </label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="name2" value="2" class="checkbox_round"> check box1 </label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="name3" value="3" class="checkbox_round"> check box1 </label>
```

Comment: do you have any check mark css or svg etc.

Comment: @ahmeticat, I don't have any svg. Is it possible to do using css?

Comment: You can embed an image as a background of the checkbox, standing in for your checkmark. You can use an SVG for that.

Comment: may this link help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827745/center-a-check-tick-within-a-custom-check-box

Comment: @HienNguyen, thanks for the link..give me some time to check

Comment: Please consider common user experiences, user can recognise your checkbox as radios since they are circular. The shape of these kind of elements should not be altered.

Comment: @MattiaAstorino, Yes, I agreed with your point. I added a message before choosing the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a background image. I suggest you an svg.

```css
.checkbox_round {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.checkbox_round:hover {
  border-color: #000;
}

.checkbox_round:checked {
  background-image: url(https://cdns.iconmonstr.com/wp-content/assets/preview/2012/240/iconmonstr-check-mark-1.png);
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="name1" value="1" class="checkbox_round"> check box1 </label>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: Yes, I used your answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a checkmark using CSS or just use a unicode checkmark. You can also just add an image, which has already been suggested.

Here are the first two possible ways:

```css
.checkbox_round {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.checkbox_round:hover {
  border-color: #000;
}

.checkbox_round {
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox_round:checked {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.checkbox_round:checked:before {
  content: "✓";
  left: 3px;
  top: -2px;
  position: absolute;
}

.checkbox2:checked:before {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  left: 3px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="name1" value="1" class="checkbox_round"> check box1 </label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="name2" value="2" class="checkbox_round checkbox2"> check box1 </label>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check